# Using Selenium IDE with replaceALL javescript to check button names

Tags: selenium

I am working with a website that has a button whose name will change depending on the area we are looking at.

eg

```
Page for Cats will have a button called (Search Cats)
Page for Dogs will have a button called (Search Dogs)
```

There are also a number of other buttons on that page that don't change.

I've created an array of the page names, and also an array with all the button names, but for the Search button I have the name "Search >PAGENAME<" I was hoping I could use the Javascript replace or replace.all to sort out what button name I should be looking for.

| Command | Target | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store | ${pageArray} | pageName |
| Store | ${buttonArray} | buttonName |
| execute script | return '${buttonName}'.replaceAll('>PAGENAME<', '${pageName}') | buttonName |

The result from this is `arguments[0]`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm pretty sure the goal is not to simply SEARCH for a button. Are you trying to click it? If you are, look into XPATH and anchor off an element that doesn't change to reach that button, and click via a relative path via other relationships. There's no point of searching for something that changes.

Comment: And for questions like this, it helps nobody to paraphrase what you're trying to search. Put up actual HTML code of said button, and multiple samples of what changes so people have an idea of exactly what is happening.

Or just put up the URL of the actual site so we can directly look at the real data and give you real code.

Comment: Hi @Nelson, the issue is not to do with the HTML code, I have no issues with checking for tests on the page, my issue is how to create the Button name to look for since that button will change its name depending on the page being looked at.

Comment: xpath has more powerful relative lookup so if you're using Selenium, you can use that. Anchor on a static unchanging element, then target the button that changes. What are you trying to DO with said button?

Comment: I just want to check that the button is displayed with the correct text, everything behind it stays static, just the text changes.

Comment: Then XPATH relative lookup is still the way to go, but without access to the actual site, it'll take some work for you to figure out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking at this for a long time, I eventually worked out what I did wrong ... I don't need the 's around the variables.

I also needed to tweak the code a bit to make it work how I wanted.

The end result is

| Command | Target | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store | ${pageArray} | pageName |
| Store | ${buttonArray} | buttonName |
| execute script | return jsResult=${buttonName}.replaceAll('>PAGENAME<', ${pageName}) | buttonName |

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Community, this goes to show the problem with a Bot looking over things.
The answer I have given is correct for the question asked. I'm not sure how it is not clear as it explains what was wrong and the correct solution.